# setState of object using properties coming from a "ref"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, setstate

I have an initial state object with coordinates `x = 0 and y = 0`, which I want to update when the html element the ref is attached to gets rendered.

Typescript however is telling me that the properties I am trying to access in useEffect do not exist, with errors such as

```
Property 'offsetWidth' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

.

```
Property 'offsetHeight' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

How can I define what I want to set in the setState method?

```
  const HierarchyScene = () => {
  const [initialTreePosition, setInitialTreePosition] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  })
  const hierarchyContainerRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hierarchyContainerRef) {
      setInitialTreePosition({
        x: hierarchyContainerRef?.current?.offsetWidth || 0,
        y: hierarchyContainerRef?.current?.offsetHeight || 0
      })
    }
  }, [hierarchyContainerRef])

  return (
    <Box ref={hierarchyContainerRef}>
      <Tree translate={initialTreePosition} />
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Preface:** Beware that even after solving the type problem, if things are resized, your component's tree position information could be *incorrect*. Ideally, avoid storing that information in state entirely, and use it from the ref every time you need it. Or even better, *if possible*, avoid needing it at all.

---

You have to tell TypeScript what the ref will reference, by providing the type argument. For instance, if you were going to use the `ref` on a `div`, it would be:

```typescript
// **IF** it were going to be a `div`
const hierarchyContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFLIBm1xAonXUhnAL5x1QQhwARFFQZBAbgBQktBAB2heABURSOAF44AChwwoKBQBsKSTgC5ceg4WOULOAB4W5+EACMkUcXACez1x5eXJwAlBoAfHAAPAAmwABu4br6RiYAdA6c2MnWtkhpPpxRAPRxiVIy8opwABLAnihQaAAWPiRoSHJqmlph6pE4knBwsgrwANrAcsAwwCiGKkhIAAoQhDPA8tjEMACS07PziytrG-IAuhoExGQmOkPDcE5wAAyYD8N+rw+hD6PVzXq+iarQAwvJyFNPPQrjR6FEakoALIAGQAIgkmIYkCBOjBwloXIZDCFpMMaCw2BgtL0IrgPnBgHRtICGiCfOC5JCulB6GFBo9Hjt9hsjqpVutZvJ7oLBc9WcCWhyISgobykHQAPxpND4KAiLnaiCsHYAdWAMRgzTgAB8ba93rLHl8FY0lZzudCNdrdfq8UaTUgYDUkMAAObNeB275O36Czg-bDjV3sj2qnn0c6kh4iGB6uTaBmxBJwER0dQ4FPulVq+iccIM4ZRY5wKypSgVqaihbi05SuTcYoNwUlMrDuCkzhAA)

In your actual code, it's a `Box`, which [looks like](https://v4.mui.com/components/box/) it renders a `div` so I assume it forwards the ref to the `div`, but you may need something more specific to Material-UI. The fundamental thing is you have to say what the `ref` will refer to.

Digging around in Material-UI, I can't see that `Box` directly supports `ref` despite [this](https://v4.mui.com/guides/composition/#caveat-with-refs) suggesting that it does. `BoxProps` doesn't seem to have `ref` on it. The `Box` documentation lists `children`, `clone`, and `component` and  says *"Any other properties supplied will be used by the style functions or spread to the root element."* but the TypeScript type doesn't seem to support doing that.

You may have to suppress the error using `ref` on `Box`, but perhaps the Material-UI folks can help with using refs on their components.

Comment: Actually the newest version of MUI supports ref on Box.

Now the code with useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null) pleases Typescript, but with useRef<Box>(null) it says "'Box' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Box'?ts(2749)"
Should I just use HTMLDivElement and be done with it?

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer - Ah, the TypeScript playground doesn't support that version yet (I tried importing from `@mui/material/Box` but it failed). Using a `div` may be easiest. :-)